# Evento do JavaScript se repetir em outros IDs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, foreach

Queria fazer um JavaScript se repetisse em outros componentes da tela, neste exemplo que estou passando fiz um foreach e dentro dele coloquei meu javascript. a intenção é que ele se repetisse 10 vezes, mas ele só funciona uma vez. existe algo similar a isso que estou tentando fazer? a intenção é que as Ids fossem variadas a cada foreach, mas eu colocando o +i ou não ele sempre executa em uma única div.

```
@for (var i = 10; i < 21; i++)
{
    <p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>

    <p id="demo+@i"></p>

    <script>
        var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

        function myTimer() {
            var d = new Date();
            document.getElementById("demo"+@i).innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabio, o seu problema está no nome da `tag <p>`, ela está ficando algo como `demo+10` ao invès de `demo10`.

O segundo ponto, você está declarando o myTimer no escopo global, então a cada interação sua, você está o sobrescrevendo, então uma saida é fazer um `IIFE`.

```
@for (var i = 10; i < 21; i++)
{
    <p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
    <p id="demo@i"></p>

    <script>
        var myVar = (function () {
            function myTimer() {
                var d = new Date();
                document.getElementById("demo@i").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            }
            return setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
        })();
    </script>
}
```

lembrando que está abordagem está longe do ideal, o melhor a se fazer seria colocar uma classe para a tag

e ter um unico setInterval.

```
@for (var i = 10; i < 21; i++)
{
    <p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
    <p id="demo@i" class="demo"></p>    
}

<script>
    var demos = document.querySelectorAll(".demo");
    function myTimer() {
        var d = new Date();
        for (i = 0; i < demos.length; i++) {
          demos[i].innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();;
        }
    }
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Poxa cara, Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso que estava querendo entender, vai me ajudar muito. valeu